# Save and use eigenvectors from PCA

Tags: command, stata, pca

I performed a Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in Stata.

My dataset includes eight financial indicators that vary across 9 countries.

For example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str7 Country double(Investment Profit Income Tax Repayment Leverage Interest Liquidity) int Year
"France"    -.1916055239385184  .046331346724579184  .16438012750896466    .073106839282063 30.373216652548326  4.116650784492168  3.222219873614461  .01453109309122077 2010
"UK"       -.09287803170279468   .10772082765154019  .19475363707485557  .05803923583546618 31.746409646181174  9.669982727208433 1.2958094802269167 .014273374324088752 2010
"US"       -.06262935107629553   .08674901201182428   .1241593221865416  .13387194413811226 25.336612638526013  11.14330064161111  1.954785887176916 .008355601163285917 2010
"Italy"   -.038025847122363045    .1523162032749684  .23885658237030563   .2057478638900476  31.02007902336988 2.9660938817562292   6.12544787693943 .011694993164234125 2010
"Germany"  -.05454795914578491   .06287079763890834  .09347194572148769  .08730237262847926 35.614342337621174  12.03770488195981 1.1958205191308358 .012467084153714813 2010
"Spain "   -.09133982259799572    .1520056836126315  .20905656056324853  .21054797530580743 30.133833346916546 2.0623245902645073  5.122615899157435 .013545432336873187 2010
"Sweden"   -.05403262462960799   .20463787181576967  .22924827352771968  .05655833155565016  20.30540887860061 10.392313613725324  .8634381995636089 .008030624504967313 2010
"Norway "  -.07560184571862992   .08383822093909514  .15469418498932822  .06569716455818478 29.568228705840234 14.383460621594622 1.5561013535825234 .012843159364225464 2010
"Algeria"   -.0494187835163535  .056252436429004446  .09174672864585759  .08143181185307143  34.74103858167055 15.045254276254616 1.2074942921860699 .011578038401820303 2010
"France"   -.03831442432584342   .14722819896988698  .22035417794604084  .12183886462162773  28.44763045286005 12.727100288710087  1.405629911115614 .011186908059399987 2011
"UK"       -.05002189329928202   .16833493262244398   .2288402623558823  .04977050186975224 27.640103129372747  11.17376089844228 1.1764542835994092 .008386726178729322 2011
"US"        -.0871005985124144   .10270482619857023   .1523559355903486  .06775742210623094 26.840586700880362 10.783899184031576  1.454011947763254 .013501919089967212 2011
"Italy"     -.1069324103590126   -.5877872620957578 -.47469302172710803   .2004436360021364 23.133243742952658 5.3936761686065875  4.532771849692548 .012586313916956204 2011
"Germany"  -.05851794344524515   .09960345907923154    .136805115392161   .1373407846168154   32.6182637042919 14.109738344526052 1.5077699357228835 .013200993625042274 2011
"Spain "   -.10650743527105216 -.015785638597076792   .1808727613216441  .05038848927405154  28.22206251292902 10.839614113486853 1.5021425852392374 .012076771099482617 2011
"Sweden"   -.09678946710644694   .11801761803893955  .18569993056826523   .1481844716617448 27.439283362903794  5.771154420635893  5.493437819181101 .013820243145673811 2011
"Norway "  -.04263379351591438   .09931719473864983  .14469611775596314   .0796835513869996  26.68561168581991  14.06385602832082 1.5200488174887825  .01029136242440406 2011
"Algeria"  -.04871983526465598    .2139061303228528   .2728647845448156 .056537570099712456  22.50263575072073 16.919641035094685  .7539881754626142 .009734650338902404 2011
end
```

I called my first component "indebtedness" and my second one "profitability", after rotation.

I have the same data for 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014 and so on. I want to use the matrix of weights Stata computed for 2010 and apply it to 2011, 2012, 2013 separately. My goal is to compare the indebtedness and the profitability between countries over time.

To do this, I use the `estimate save` and `estimates use` commands (Chapter 20 of Stata manual on estimates and the post-estimation PCA command help).

However, I can't understand what Stata is saving. Is it saving the scores computed for 2010 or the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

This is the code I use:

```
tempfile pca
save `pca'
use `pca' if Year==2010
global xlist Investment Profit Income Tax Repayment Leverage Interest Liquidity
pca $xlist, components(2)
estimates save pcaest, replace
predict score
summarize score
use `pca' if Year==2011, clear
estimates use pcaest
predict score
summarize score
```

1. Does this method and code seem correct to you?
2. I'd also like to save the matrix of weights and create a new vector `Z=b|1,1]*investment+...`.

Comment: Please provide us with example data using the `dataex` command in Stata. Screenshots are not helpful and without data we cannot replicate anything and thus help you. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @PearlySpencer done :) Thank you for your feedback

Comment: I want to save the matrix of eigenvectors.The aim of a PCA is to find the components Z(z1..zP) which are a linear combination of the original variables X1. My original variables are for the year 2010. PCA computes the matrix W or the eigenvector matrix. Thus, I have Z=W' X1. Now, let's assume that X2 is my data for 2011. If I use the matrix W computed in the first step and multiply it by X2. I should obtain the components for the year 2011 which will be comparable to 2010. Maybe I am absolutely wrong. But this seems logical to me. However, I don't know if the command -estimates save- is good.

Comment: I have no experience with PCA but to get the matrix of eigenvectors = components _after_ you run the `pca` command you type `matrix A = e(L)`. Similarly, for the matrix of eigenvalues (sorted) you type `matrix B = e(Ev)`.

Comment: Ok! But how do I save this matrix and reuse it for 2011 database?

Comment: See my answer. You eventually get two variables A1 and A2 with the two components. With what do you want to multiply these?

Comment: Nothing in your code does any rotation so far as I can see.

Comment: @NickCox my original code did the Varmax rotation. But I did not keep this part of the code in the question I sent. Do you have any advice to give me, regarding my question? BTW, thank you for the editing

Comment: @poofidoudou what additional advice do you need? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using your toy example for year 2010:

```
clear

input str7 Country double(Investment Profit Income Tax Repayment Leverage Interest Liquidity) int Year
"France"    -.1916055239385184  .046331346724579184  .16438012750896466    .073106839282063 30.373216652548326  4.116650784492168  3.222219873614461  .01453109309122077 2010
"UK"       -.09287803170279468   .10772082765154019  .19475363707485557  .05803923583546618 31.746409646181174  9.669982727208433 1.2958094802269167 .014273374324088752 2010
"US"       -.06262935107629553   .08674901201182428   .1241593221865416  .13387194413811226 25.336612638526013  11.14330064161111  1.954785887176916 .008355601163285917 2010
"Italy"   -.038025847122363045    .1523162032749684  .23885658237030563   .2057478638900476  31.02007902336988 2.9660938817562292   6.12544787693943 .011694993164234125 2010
"Germany"  -.05454795914578491   .06287079763890834  .09347194572148769  .08730237262847926 35.614342337621174  12.03770488195981 1.1958205191308358 .012467084153714813 2010
"Spain "   -.09133982259799572    .1520056836126315  .20905656056324853  .21054797530580743 30.133833346916546 2.0623245902645073  5.122615899157435 .013545432336873187 2010
"Sweden"   -.05403262462960799   .20463787181576967  .22924827352771968  .05655833155565016  20.30540887860061 10.392313613725324  .8634381995636089 .008030624504967313 2010
"Norway "  -.07560184571862992   .08383822093909514  .15469418498932822  .06569716455818478 29.568228705840234 14.383460621594622 1.5561013535825234 .012843159364225464 2010
"Algeria"   -.0494187835163535  .056252436429004446  .09174672864585759  .08143181185307143  34.74103858167055 15.045254276254616 1.2074942921860699 .011578038401820303 2010
end
```

I get the following results:

```
local xlist Investment Profit Income Tax Repayment Leverage Interest Liquidity
pca `xlist', components(2)

Principal components/correlation                 Number of obs    =          9
                                                 Number of comp.  =          2
                                                 Trace            =          8
    Rotation: (unrotated = principal)            Rho              =     0.7468

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Component |   Eigenvalue   Difference         Proportion   Cumulative
    -------------+------------------------------------------------------------
           Comp1 |      3.43566      .896796             0.4295       0.4295
           Comp2 |      2.53887      1.23215             0.3174       0.7468
           Comp3 |      1.30672      .750756             0.1633       0.9102
           Comp4 |      .555959      .472866             0.0695       0.9797
           Comp5 |     .0830926     .0181769             0.0104       0.9900
           Comp6 |     .0649157     .0526462             0.0081       0.9982
           Comp7 |     .0122695    .00975098             0.0015       0.9997
           Comp8 |    .00251849            .             0.0003       1.0000
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

Principal components (eigenvectors) 

    ------------------------------------------------
        Variable |    Comp1     Comp2 | Unexplained 
    -------------+--------------------+-------------
      Investment |   0.0004   -0.3837 |       .6262 
          Profit |   0.3896   -0.3794 |       .1131 
          Income |   0.4621   -0.1162 |        .232 
             Tax |   0.4146    0.1236 |       .3706 
       Repayment |  -0.1829    0.4747 |       .3131 
        Leverage |  -0.4685   -0.2596 |      .07464 
        Interest |   0.4580    0.2625 |       .1045 
       Liquidity |  -0.0082    0.5643 |       .1913 
    ------------------------------------------------
```

To see what items the `pca` command returns type:

```
 ereturn list

scalars:
                  e(N) =  9
                  e(f) =  2
                e(rho) =  .7468162625387222
              e(trace) =  8
              e(lndet) =  -13.76082122673546
               e(cond) =  36.93476257313668

macros:
            e(cmdline) : "pca Investment Profit Income Tax Repayment Leverage Interest Liquidity, components(2)"
                e(cmd) : "pca"
              e(title) : "Principal components"
       e(marginsnotok) : "_ALL"
          e(estat_cmd) : "pca_estat"
         e(rotate_cmd) : "pca_rotate"
            e(predict) : "pca_p"
              e(Ctype) : "correlation"
         e(properties) : "nob noV eigen"

matrices:
                e(sds) :  1 x 8
              e(means) :  1 x 8
                  e(C) :  8 x 8
                e(Psi) :  1 x 8
                 e(Ev) :  1 x 8
                  e(L) :  8 x 2

functions:
             e(sample)
```

One way to save the returned matrix containing the eigenvectors as variables for the next year is to create a copy of the matrix and load the 2011 data:

```
matrix A = e(L)

clear

input str7 Country double(Investment Profit Income Tax Repayment Leverage Interest Liquidity) int Year
"France"   -.03831442432584342   .14722819896988698  .22035417794604084  .12183886462162773  28.44763045286005 12.727100288710087  1.405629911115614 .011186908059399987 2011
"UK"       -.05002189329928202   .16833493262244398   .2288402623558823  .04977050186975224 27.640103129372747  11.17376089844228 1.1764542835994092 .008386726178729322 2011
"US"        -.0871005985124144   .10270482619857023   .1523559355903486  .06775742210623094 26.840586700880362 10.783899184031576  1.454011947763254 .013501919089967212 2011
"Italy"     -.1069324103590126   -.5877872620957578 -.47469302172710803   .2004436360021364 23.133243742952658 5.3936761686065875  4.532771849692548 .012586313916956204 2011
"Germany"  -.05851794344524515   .09960345907923154    .136805115392161   .1373407846168154   32.6182637042919 14.109738344526052 1.5077699357228835 .013200993625042274 2011
"Spain "   -.10650743527105216 -.015785638597076792   .1808727613216441  .05038848927405154  28.22206251292902 10.839614113486853 1.5021425852392374 .012076771099482617 2011
"Sweden"   -.09678946710644694   .11801761803893955  .18569993056826523   .1481844716617448 27.439283362903794  5.771154420635893  5.493437819181101 .013820243145673811 2011
"Norway "  -.04263379351591438   .09931719473864983  .14469611775596314   .0796835513869996  26.68561168581991  14.06385602832082 1.5200488174887825  .01029136242440406 2011
"Algeria"  -.04871983526465598    .2139061303228528   .2728647845448156 .056537570099712456  22.50263575072073 16.919641035094685  .7539881754626142 .009734650338902404 2011
end
```

Then you can simply use the `svmat` command:

```
svmat A

list A* if _n < 9

     +-----------------------+
     |        A1          A2 |
     |-----------------------|
  1. |  .0003921    -.383703 |
  2. |  .3895898   -.3793983 |
  3. |  .4621098   -.1162487 |
  4. |  .4146066    .1235683 |
  5. | -.1828703    .4746658 |
     |-----------------------|
  6. | -.4685374   -.2596268 |
  7. |   .457974    .2624738 |
  8. | -.0081538    .5643047 |
     +-----------------------+
```

**EDIT:**

Revised according to comments:

```
use X1, clear

local xlist Investment Profit Income Tax Repayment Leverage Interest Liquidity

forvalues i = 1 / 5 {
    pca `xlist' if year == 201`i', components(2)
    matrix A201`i' = e(L)
    svmat A201`i'

    generate B201`i'1 = (A201`i'1 * Investment) + (A201`i'1 * Profit) + ///
                        (A201`i'1 * Income) + (A201`i'1 * Tax) + ///
                        (A201`i'1 * Repayment) + (A201`i'1 * Leverage) + ///
                        (A201`i'1 * Interest) + (A201`i'1 * Liquidity)

    generate B201`i'2 = (A201`i'2 * Investment) + (A201`i'2 * Profit) + ///
                        (A201`i'2 * Income) + (A201`i'2 * Tax) + ///
                        (A201`i'2 * Repayment) + (A201`i'2 * Leverage) + ///
                        (A201`i'2 * Interest) + (A201`i'2 * Liquidity)
}
```

Comment: Ok ! I see. How can I get the matrix back when I use the 2011 database?

Comment: It depends on how you have the data for different years but the idea is the same: If you save the matrix every time after you use the `pca` command you can simply create the variables using the `svmat` command and repeat. See my revised answer. You can also automate this using a loop.

Comment: This is useful thank you. But as I said in my question. I am not familiar with matrix in Stata. What is the next step after svmat A?

Comment: What do you mean? It depends on what you want to do. The `svmat` command creates variables from a specified matrix. What do you want to do with the variables?

Comment: I want to bring new dataset X1 which is my original dataset. But I just want to keep the data for 2011. Then, I want to create a new vector Z1(8 lines 1 row) equal to X1(8 lines 8 row) multiplied by A1 (8 lines one row). and another vector Z2 (8 lines 1 row) equal to X1(8 lines 8 row) multiplied by A2 (8 lines one row). Z1 and Z2 would be my scores for 2011.  Then, I want to bring the data for 2012, and do the same thing. Z

Comment: See my revised answer. Stata has no vectors - it has variables.

Comment: @poofidoudou If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it using the check-mark.

Comment: @poofidoudou in your question you mention `Z=b|1,1]*investment+...` Do you want to multiply the new variable to be the product of each variable or their sum? What you mention in your last comment is different. My code does the latter.